# node.js SPA webapp - all communications via websockets

Tags: node.js, rest, websocket

I have a SPA application (Backbone on client and node.js on server). It all communication in both directions is through via websockets. Now I wondered - it's a good idea? What are the cons before approach: the client sends data to the server via the REST API, and server sends data to client via websockets?

thanks.

UPD:

I have websockets in any case because my app is multiroom chat.

Answer (score 2):

Even if you only consider RPC ("Remote Procedure Calls"), REST is less capable than WebSocket.

REST, since it runs over HTTP, cannot pipeline RPCs. Each HTTP connection can only serve 1 RPC synchronously. And browsers limit the number of parallel HTTP connections to a given origin.

With RPC over WebSocket, you can fire off 100 RPCs pipelined, and process RPC returns asynchronously as they come in.

Then, with WebSocket, you can have server-initiated notifications as well. E.g. you can have full-flavored Publish & Subscribe.

[WAMP](http://wamp.ws/) ("The Web Application Messaging Protocol") runs over WebSocket and was designed exactly for this: SPAs that need 2 messaging patterns in 1 protocol - RPC and PubSub.

Disclaimer: I am original author of WAMP and work for Tavendo.

Answer (score 1):

If server needs uncertain time to prepare data, it may be a good idea though
basically there is no reason to use websocket(socket.io) for REST API.

because of what REST API stands for,You don't have to keep connection stablished nor don't have to wait for someones action like broadcasting server.

**EDIT answering the comment**

even if you already used websocket,it doesn't mean you can't handle normal req/res.

RESTapi with websocket is like

get request -> server response -> client try io.connect(); -> connection established -> server send data to the client thru websocket

and normal REST API is like

get request -> server responce

which do you choose?

Comment: But what if I have websockets in any case? I've updated the question